# How can i navigate to a specific screen while i tap on the push notificatios

Tags: swift, swiftui

I connected my project to firebase(FCM) for notifications. Iam getting notifications but i cant navigate to required screen while iam tapping on notifications. For me while i tap on notification if the app is on foreground its showing the same screen while app is in background its showing the tab screen which i gave. i want to navigate to specific screen like chats or alerts.

[Programmatic Navigation after opening notification SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70749561/programmatic-navigation-after-opening-notification-swiftui?noredirect=1&lq=1) I tried this link code i didn't get the reqired solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66283978/swiftui-open-a-specific-view-when-user-opens-a-push-notification

If not can you post the relevant parts of your code where you expect the navigation/alerts to happen. Others may be able to help better if they can see what work you have done so far.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a delegate of `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` and implement two of its methods which are listed below.

```
     func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
            completionHandler([.alert,.badge,.sound])
        }
        func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
            print(response.notification.request.content.userInfo)
           //Handle your tap here
            completionHandler()
            
        }
```