# onChange not detecting AppDelegate Update in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, appdelegate

I have an AppDelegate in my SwiftUI app, and I set a ViewModel like so:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate, ObservableObject {
    var AppNavigator: ApplicationNavigator = ApplicationNavigator()
}
```

This is my ApplicationNavigator View Model:

```
class ApplicationNavigator: ObservableObject {
    @Published var applicationNavigation: ApplicationNavigatorItem = ApplicationNavigatorItem(id: "default")
}
```

Where ApplicationNavigator takes an `ApplicationNavigatorItem`:

```
struct ApplicationNavigatorItem: Identifiable, Codable  {
    var id: String? = UUID().uuidString
}
```

And when a user taps on a remote notification, I update the `AppNavigator` in my AppDelegate with a new `ApplicationNavigatorItem`:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                              didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                              withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    self.AppNavigator.applicationNavigation = ApplicationNavigatorItem(
        id: newUUID
    )
}
```

Now to the SwiftUI part.

In my views, I've shared `appDelegate` as an environment object with my view, since I want to listen for changes to `appDelgate.AppNavigator.applicationNavigation.id`.

I've set an `onChanged` modifier to my main view:

```
.onChange(of: appDelegate.AppNavigator.applicationNavigation.id) { _ in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        appDelegate.AppNavigator.navigate()
    }
}
```

And this *only works* if the user is tapping the push notification when the app is in the background.

However, if a user receives the push notification while they're inside the app, and it is active, nothing happens when they tap it.

Oddly enough, after tapping a notification while inside the app, (where nothing happens) if I swipe the app up until it's scenePhase is `.inactive` || `.background`, and re-open the app, the code inside `.onChange(..) { _ in // code }` finally runs.

I've even put a `Text(appDelegate.AppNavigator.applicationNavigation.id!)` on the main view to see if `appDelegate.AppNavigator.applicationNavigation.id` has changed, but it doesn't if I'm still inside the app.

I'm trying to send the user to a specific view if they tap on a notification, and sometimes they might be inside the app. Can anyone help me see where I've made a mistake?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I've 1. solved the problem, and 2. learned something very cool about SwiftUI!

Instead of initialising `ApplicationNavigator` inside of `appDelegate`, I can create an @ObservedObject in my view:

```
@ObservedObject var appNavigator = ApplicationNavigator.shared
```

And I can update my `.onChange` modifier to:

```
.onChange(of: appNavigator.applicationNavigation.id) { _ in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // Do navigation things
    }
}
```

And then when I want to update the `ApplicationNavigatorItem` in my `appDelegate`, I can set it on `ApplicationNavigator.shared`:

```
ApplicationNavigator.shared.applicationNavigation = ApplicationNavigatorItem(id: newUUID)
```

I give thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66284621/19020089) that helped me out!

P.S. If you attach an `.onAppear { }` to your main view, wherever you detect the change, and run the code you execute in your `.onChange` , it will work even if the app is *not open* at all!

Comment: This is a very clever and elegant solution I was facing a similar issue and your solution was a nice road to solve my issue, thanks!