# SWIFTUI Local Notification navigates to (sheet or modal) View

Tags: swiftui

I got local notifications to work. Asking permission, setting, removing, etc. What I can't seem to get right is navigating to a (detail) view upon clicking the notification.

I have the following code:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse) async { gotoview }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66283978/swiftui-open-a-specific-view-when-user-opens-a-push-notification

Comment: That answer uses isActive... The isActive implementation of NavigationLink is deprecated in iOS 16